# android AlertDialog dismiss is not called

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I've got some problem..
Well, I create `AlertDialog` using `AlertDialog.Builder`, than I using `setContentView` for setting `OK` and `Cancel` buttons and hang up some actions on the `dismiss()` method. BUT..when I touching anything else this buttons, `dismiss()` is not called.

So, my question is, Which methods are invokes when i touching and how can i call my methods in this case(touching anything else)?
Thns!

Comment: put your code and error log if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set `onCancelListener()` on the  dialog.